# Convert SQL(Row_Number) Query into Linq in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to convert below `SQL Query` to Linq expression in `C#`(MVC)?

```
with cte
as
(
select *,rank() over(partition by LineClass order by LineClassId) as rownum 
from MT_LineClass where ProjectId =1 
)
select * from cte where  rownum=1
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not use your existing query?

Comment: Please clarify what do you want to achieve? Why do you need row number in Linq? You can iterate the collection later with the index (as an example)

Comment: i need two columns i.e; lineclassid  which is column 1 and lineclass is column 2, in this column 2 data has duplicates , i need lineclass column data which eliminates duplicates with their respective id after eliminating duplicate of column 2 in linq

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = from tbl in MT_LineClass
          group tbl.lineclassid by tbl.lineclass into g
          select new { LineClass = g.Key, LineClassIds = g.ToList() };
```

You can use other than `ToList` operations to get the id (eq `First`, `Max` etc)

Comment: anyone answer the question

Comment: this answer is based on your comment. you have lineClass and the array of corresponding ids in the `res` object. this is what you need, isn't it?

Comment: The above solution is not working ,  i need ids of  corresponding filtered lineclass

Comment: In your query you take the first one. change the last line in my query to `select new { LineClass = g.Key, LineClassId = g.First() };`

Answer (score 0):

```
var lst = (from t in context.MT_LineClass
                       where t.ProjectId == projId
                       group t by t.LineClass into g
                       select new Mt_Lineclass
                       {
                           lineId = g.Select(t => t.LineClassId).FirstOrDefault(),
                           Lineclass = g.Select(t => t.LineClass).FirstOrDefault()

                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: finally This is the answer i got from my colleague  which worked out for me